# How to Work Highslide Javascript in Spring Application?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring

Actually in my Spring Application Working HighSlide JavaScript for display dynamic pages like popups.

This is my Working Code With HighSlide:

```
<a href="new.html" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe', width:800} )">New</a>
```

When we click New HyperLink Slider open and show `new.html` page.

But Spring Application we are working with `MVC` objects so we have to return model and display the view Object.

And we have to give Hyperlink as..

```
<a href="#" onclick="onClick_new()">New</a>

fucnction onClick_new(){
  javascript:$('#PROFILE_HEADER').submit();
  return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe', width:800} 
}
```

But This is not Working even previous result also not coming...

Please help me.. give suggestions..